# How do i animate the fill of an inline svg to change with mouse position (in parent div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Is it possible to animate the fill of a inline svg path, to change as the mouse moves around the page ?

Comment: yes it is, what part of doing this are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

In the example in the code snippet below, the x and y positions of the mouse are monitored using the "mousemove" event and the screenX and screenY properties of the event object. Red and green colors values are set depending on those coordinates, and an rgb fill color string is constructed and imposed on an SVG path element.

```js
var path = document.querySelector("path");

document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
  var xRatio = Math.min(1, evt.clientX / document.body.offsetWidth );
  var yRatio = Math.min(1, evt.clientY / document.body.offsetHeight);
  var red   = parseInt(255 * xRatio);
  var green = parseInt(255 * yRatio);
  var color = "rgb(" + red + ", " + green + ", 128)";
  document.querySelector("path").setAttribute("fill", color);
});
```

```css
body {
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Move your mouse over the image to see the colour-change effect.</p>
  <svg width="400" height="150">
    <path d="M10,75 C200,-100 300,120 390,75 200,250 100,30 10,75" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" fill="none" />
  </svg>
</body>
```